# CNN Model Input 0 of layer "conv2d_6" is incompatible with the layer

Tags: conv-neural-network, data-science

I am training a CNN model to classify a dataset with 1896 files belonging 2 classes.
I create a model but when I train it i get a error message

I tried to create a CNN model. I defined this:

```
IMAGE_SIZE_1 = 1280
IMAGE_SIZE_2 = 720
BATCH_SIZE=30
EPOCHS = 20
CHANNELS = 2
```

I did some resizind and rescaling:

```
resize_and_rescale = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Resizing(IMAGE_SIZE_1,IMAGE_SIZE_2),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.Rescaling(1.0/255)
])
```

I also did data argumentation:

```
data_argumentation = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical"),
    layers.experimental.preprocessing.RandomRotation(0.2)
])
```

The model I create was the follow one:

```
input_shape = ( BATCH_SIZE,IMAGE_SIZE_1, IMAGE_SIZE_2, CHANNELS)
n_classes = 2

model = models.Sequential([
    resize_and_rescale,
    data_argumentation,
    #Input layer
    layers.Conv2D(35, (3,3), activation="relu", input_shape = input_shape),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    #Pooling
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,2), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
    layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),
   
    #Flatenning
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64,activation="relu"),
    #Output LAyer
    layers.Dense(n_classes, activation="softmax")
])
```

```
model.compile(
optimizer="adam",
loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
metrics=["accuracy"])
```

But when i try to train it:

```
history = model.fit(
train_ds,
epochs=EPOCHS,
verbose=1,
batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
validation_data=val_ds)
```

I receive this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13368\3834416336.py in <module>
----> 1 history = model.fit(
      2 train_ds,
      3 epochs=EPOCHS,
      4 verbose=1,
      5 batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     68             # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69             # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70             raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71         finally:
     72             del filtered_tb

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in tf__train_function(iterator)
     13                 try:
     14                     do_return = True
---> 15                     retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
     16                 except:
     17                     do_return = False

ValueError: in user code:

    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1023, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 277, in assert_input_compatibility
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential).
    
    Input 0 of layer "conv2d_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2, but received input with shape (None, 1280, 720, 3)
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'sequential_3' (type Sequential):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 1280, 720, 3), dtype=float32)
      • training=True
      • mask=None
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you CHANNELS should be 3